# How would one go about Accessing Variable Addresses in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, pointers, vb6, vb6-migration

I have to upgrade a legacy VB6 app to VB.NET; this app uses a function call from a .dll that takes a memory address as one of it's parameters.  The VB6 app does this with the VarPtr() function, but this function does not exist in .NET.  How do I retrieve the memory location of a variable in .NET?

-Edit1

For example

```
aVariable1 = aFunctionCall(VarPtr(aVariable2))
```

-Edit2

The exact function call is in a DLL called FTD2XX.DLL and the exact call is

```
FT_STATUS = FT_ListDevices(arg1, arg2, _
    FT_LIST_BY_INDEX or FT_OPEN_BY_SERIAL_NUMBER)
```

Comment: What is the type of the arg1 and arg2 variables?

Answer (score 1):

Trying to pass addresses of something in managed code (.NET) to an unmanaged DLL might not be the best plan. VB6 and VB.NET don't have a lot in common beyond similar syntax and a similar sounding name.  You may need to to pin the memory before passing an address.  You will need to look into platform invoke:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx

Answer (score 1):

It is automatic when you declare the external function with the Declare keyword.  All you have to do is declare the argument with ByRef.  That forces the P/Invoke marshaller to pass a pointer to the native code.  Same thing as VarPtr.  Only if you pass ByVal do you have to explicitly convert the passed argument to a pointer.